# XCode Swift 3 UITableViewController Cell doesn't show

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I am exporting json file from itunes api>converted that to a json file>send that to firebase> brought that in to a dictionary file here and now I am trying to put that into a tableview but it does not seem to work and I have no clue why. I checked that:
1. The file that I imported was successfully converted into a dictionary.
2. Datasource and delegate is connected to this UITableViewController file.
3. Put other arrays to check if my connections were right(and it worked but it does not work at all if I use the data that I brought in with Firebase)
4. I put cell style as subtitle and type as dynamic.

Below is the UITableViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class TableViewController1: UITableViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var rank = [String]()
var song = [[String]]()
var artist = [[String]]()
var tna = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    self.ref.child("top100itunes").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let jsonfile = snapshot.value! as! String
        //print(jsonfile)
        let jsondict:[String:Any] = self.convertToDictionary(text: jsonfile)!
        for (key, value) in jsondict {
            if key != nil {
                self.rank.append(key)
                if value != nil{
                    self.tna.append(value as! String)
                }
            }
        }
        for x in self.tna{
            if x != nil {
                for (key,value) in self.convertToDictionary(text: x)!{
                    self.song.append([key])
                    self.artist.append([value as! String])
                }
            }
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}


// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()


func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return self.song.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.song[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.rank[section]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.song[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.artist[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

}
```

The json file that I imported is in the structure like:

```
{ 1 : { Title : Artist },
  2 : { Title : Artist }, 
  .....
}
```

Comment: You can omit the "please help" stuff. We all know what the purpose of asking a Stack Overflow question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing this:

1. viewDidLoad
2. start firebase async
3. ask for tableview number of sections/rows
4. song.count is 0
5. tableview loads with no cells
6. firebase async completes and populates song array
7. ... nothing else

After this method you should add tableView reloadData like so:

```
    for x in self.tna{
        if x != nil {
            for (key,value) in self.convertToDictionary(text: x)!{
                self.song.append([key])
                self.artist.append([value as! String])
            }
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I agree with Halfman that you should rearchitect your application to separate out the model from the controller. Read up on MVC.

I also suggest that instead of maintaining multiple arrays (i.e. song, artist, tna) you use a single struct to manage all this data.  Read up on Swift structures.

`TableViewController1` isn't an optimal choice for a controller name.  Maybe `SongListTableViewController` is more clear?

Comment: Thank you so much this cleared up a lot. The name was solely for an experimenting purpose and I have a different controller with a different name:).

Comment: Glad it cleared things up, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

observeSingleEvent() is asynchronous and numberOfRowsInSection() will be getting called before observeSingleEvent() has finished populating the data. 
If you put a call to self.tableView.reloadData() after the 2nd for loop then this will cause a refresh of the table view once the data has been populated.

Alternatively you could consider re-architecting your app so it has a separate model component that is responsible for data retrieval so that the data could have been populated before the view is launched if applicable.